# How to rewrite this partial derivative of in terms of the parameter?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood, expectation-maximization

I'm trying to estimate the parameters of a Hawkes process using an EM algorithm. I found [this](http://paleo.sscnet.ucla.edu/Lewis-Molher-EM_Preprint.pdf) paper where in the maximisation step, for parameter $\mu$, we have
$$\mu^{k+1} = \frac{\sum^n_{i=1}p^k_{ii}}{T},$$
where
$$p_{ii}^k=\frac{\mu^k}{\mu^k+\sum^{i-1}_{j=1}\alpha^k\beta^k e^{-\beta^k(t_i-t_j)}}.$$
This is achieved by setting the partial derivative of the log-likelihood
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}l=\sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{\lambda_i(t_i)}-T,$$
where
$$\lambda_i(t_i) = \mu+\sum^{i-1}_{j=1}\alpha\beta e^{-\beta(t_i-t_j)}$$
to zero and rewriting it in terms of $\mu$. However, I don't see how we arrive to this. Here's what I've tried so far:

$$\sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{\mu+\sum^{k-1}_{j=1}\alpha\beta e^{-\beta(t_i-t_j)}}-T=0 \\
\sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{\mu+\sum^{k-1}_{j=1}\alpha\beta e^{-\beta(t_i-t_j)}}=T.$$

However, I'm stuck here due to the summations.